# C++ aggregate initialization

Tags: c++

According to the [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), aggregate initialization has the following syntax:

```cpp
T object = { arg1, arg2, ... }; 
T object { arg1, arg2, ... };
T object = { .des1 = arg1 , .des2 { arg2 } ... };   
T object {.des1 = arg1 , .des2 { arg2 } ... };
```

So this would be an example of aggregate initialization:

```cpp
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
std::size_t arr[]{a,b};
```

But if an aggregate is a member of a class initialized in the member initializer list, is it still an aggregate initialization or a different type of initialization?

```cpp
struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    S(T a, T b)
        : arr{ a, b }
    {   }

    std::size_t arr[2];
};
S s{ 1, 2 };
```

Update:
I thought the question is clear, but having read the comments, I realize that I have to clarify that it is about the array member `arr`, not about `S`.

Comment: This is [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

Comment: `S` is not even an aggregate.

Comment: Is your question about the initialization of `arr` or that of `s`?

Comment: @Jason I was not asking about S, but about an aggregate that is a member of a class

Comment: @mentalmushroom Added more details. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: @mentalmushroom Don't remove parts of your question, as it invalidates the already existing answer. People reading my answer won't know which `s` I'm talking about when you removed `S s{ 1, 2 };`

Comment: @Jason Ok, let's keep it if you like. I removed it for many people started thinking that I was asking about initializing S, which wasn't the point of the question.

Comment: @mentalmushroom Your update which says that you're asking about `arr` and not `s` is enough for any future readers. Before that the question has ambiguity but now it is clear since you added a note at the end of your question. So no need to remove the `S s{1,2};`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Aggregate initialization* refers to a certain semantic of initialization, not to a syntactical form of initialization.

The syntax listed by cppreference just demonstrates the possible syntactical forms that *may* result in aggregate initialization, but they aren't *generally* aggregate initialization.

The syntactical forms are called *list initialization* instead. List initialization may only result in aggregate initialization if the object type is an aggregate type. But for aggregate types, with few exceptions, list initialization does result in aggregate initialization.

In the this case `S::arr` is an array type and so an aggregate type. Consequently `arr{ a, b }` in the constructor's initializer list is aggregate initialization of `arr` as well.

The form of initialization is determined only be the *initializer* part of the syntax, i.e. `{ a, b }`. The context in which the initializer appears, such as a variable declaration or constructor initializer list, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, `S` is not even an aggregate as it has a user-provided constructor.

Additionally, `S s{ 1, 2 };` follows the rules of [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) which have:

> Otherwise, the constructors of T are considered, in two phases:
>
> - If the previous stage does not produce a match, **all constructors of `T` participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed**. If this stage produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all).

(emphasis mine)

This means that the constructor will be used to initialize `arr`. And since `arr` is an aggregate type, it uses [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: The question is about the initialization of `arr` in the member initializer list, not the initialization of `s`.